# do column operation between two csv files

Tags: python, csv

I have two csv files like this:

file1:

```
# full part
1 30   10
```

file2:

```
# full part
1 32   15
```

I want to do column operation and output it like this:

```
listname        a        b    diff(b-a)
full            30       32    2
part            10       15    5
```

How can I do this in python?

Comment: I think you need a little more formatting to your data there. Wrap it in code ({}).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very hard to understand, but I can take a guess at what you mean:

csvdiff.py:

```
import csv

with open('file1') as file1, open('file2') as file2, open('output', 'w') as output:
    next(file1), next(file2) # skip the header lines
    c1, c2 = csv.reader(file1, delimiter=' '), csv.reader(file2, delimiter=' ')
    c3 = csv.writer(output, delimiter=' ')
    c3.writerow(['listname', 'a', 'b', 'diff(b-a)'])
    for (row1, row2) in zip(c1, c2):
        c3.writerow(('full', row1[1], row2[1], int(row2[1])-int(row1[1])))
        c3.writerow(('part', row1[2], row2[2], int(row2[2])-int(row1[2])))
```

file1:

```
full part
1 30 10
```

file2:

```
full part
1 32 15
```

output:

```
listname a b diff(b-a)
full 30 32 2
part 10 15 5
```

Is that what you wanted?

Notice that the columns in my test input aren't "lined up". If your original data was lined up, it was probably using tabs, in which case you'll want to use `delimiter='\t'` instead of `delimiter=' '`. If they really do have varying numbers of spaces (as in what you originally pasted into the question), you want to leave `delimiter=' '`, and add `skipinitialspace=True`. See [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#dialects-and-formatting-parameters) for details on all of the formatting options available.

And if you want the output to be lined up… the easiest way to do that is use string formatting to force the values to be a fixed width before printing them. For example, instead of `c3.writerow(…)` do `c3.writerow('{:<20}'.format(col) for col in …)`. If you need anything *really* fancy—like figuring out the right width for each column by going through all the rows and finding the max width of each column—you probably want to put some kind of wrapper around the `writer` (or maybe just not use `csv` at all for output).

There are a couple of tricks here:

First, use the [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module to handle parsing (and creating) CSV files for you. The really easy way to do it is with `DictReader` and `DictWriter` (that way, you don't need to skip the header row, and you can refer to the columns by names instead of by index), but since you only have two column headers for three columns, that doesn't work, so you need to use `reader` and `writer`.

Second, a `csv.reader` is just like a file, a list, or any other iterable. It's just a sequence of rows. So, if you want to go through two CSV readers in lockstep, just `zip` them together, and you get a single sequence of pairs of rows. (If you're using Python 2.x, you may want to use [`itertools.izip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) instead.)

Finally, CSV files generally don't do anything to indicate the types of the values, so `reader` just gives you strings. If you know the values are integers, and want to treat them that way, you have to call `int` on them.

Comment: yes Thank you. I am trying to format it like this. but could not be able to format the question like this

Comment: @hello_sm: Read the formatting help—or just click the code button to format the current selection as code.